# EventListnerの挙動は、サーバに置いた場合と、直接htmlを叩いた場合とで違いがあるのでしょうか？

Tags: flash, actionscript

おつかれさまです。AS初心者のjunと申します。

`EventListner`の挙動は、サーバに置いた場合と、直接htmlを叩いた場合とで違いがあるのでしょうか？

というのは、下記のように、`flashVars`で渡された外部swfを読み込み表示させようとしました。

パブリッシュしたswfおよび、参照予定の外部swfをサーバに置いて叩いてみたら、ちゃんと表示されたのですが、`index.html`をローカル上でダブルクリックすると、`onComplete`メソッドすら叩かれないのです。

なんでなんでしょうか。

■`index.html`

```
<embed src="swfPlayer.swf" width="300" height="500" FlashVars="file=test.swf">
```

■`swfPlayer/Main.as`

```
private function _load():void
{
  :
var fv: Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var file: String = String(fv["file"]);

var loader : Loader = new Loader;
var url : URLRequest = new URLRequest(file);
loader.load(url);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
  :
}
```

```
private function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    Log.t("complete");

    var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
    var content:MovieClip = loaderInfo.content as MovieClip;
    addChildAt(content, 0);

    Log.t("complete-end");
}
```

Comment: FlashVarsにファイル名を指定しているのが問題な気がします。ファイル名ではなく「http://」から始まるURLをFlashVarsに渡してみるのはどうでしょうか

Comment: 試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
具体的には下記のように行いました。

    <embed src="swfPlayer.swf" width="300" height="500" FlashVars="file=http://192.168.1.1/test/test.swf">

Chromeで動作確認を行っているのですが、デベロッパーツールのNetworkで確認する限り、test.swfをGETし200OKを返し、正常に取得出来ているように見えました。

Comment: swfの呼び出しのobjectタグとembedタグにallowScriptAccessを設定してみてはどうでしょう?
object：<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">  embed：<embed allowScriptAccess="always" ～

Answer (score 3):

Google Chromeで試されているのでしたら、
以下のようにGoogle Chromeを実行してみるのはどうでしょうか。

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Google Chromeはデフォルトだとローカルファイルへのアクセスに制限がかかるので、
それを解除するオプションです。

ローカルで試す用としてこのオプションを加えたショートカットをよく利用しています。